# jQuery .on() an element, if parent element has no class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The headline says it all, but this won't work,
The hover function works, no matter the body.

```
$("#content").on("click", "a.zoom", function(e) {
    $("body").addClass("zoomed");
}
$("#content").on("hover", "body:not(.zoomed) a.animation", function(e) {
    //stuff
}
```

I also tried the other way around, but I dont get it.

```
$("body:not(.zoomed) #content").on("hover", "a.animation", function(e) {
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: It's working here: http://jsfiddle.net/richardneililagan/Ng6hW/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. after finding out i was fiddleing in the wrong function i still couldnt get this to work, due to the hover event.

this turns out nothing (this one isnt even checking for the body class):

```
$("#content").on("hover", "a.backgroundSwitch", function(e) {
    console.log("hello?");
}, function() {
    console.log("bello!");
});
```

so i used the solution of Richard Neil Ilagan unsing the mouseover & out events.

```
$("#content").on("mouseover", "body:not(.zoomed) a.backgroundSwitch", function() {
    console.log("hello");
}).on("mouseout", "body:not(.zoomed) a.backgroundSwitch", function() {
    console.log("bello");
});
```

thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring the listener differently:

```
$(document).on("hover", "#content body:not(.zoomed) a.animation", yourHoverFunction);
```

Comment: You're doing it the `live` way, which `on` (and `delegate`) is supposed to correct. Although if you think about it, we might **actually** have to resort to this. Which is sad.

Comment: sorry guys. me stupid hacking inside the wrong function. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`on` takes advantage of event bubbling to work. In your case when you specify the root selector as `#content` and the matching selector as `body:not(.zoomed) a.animation`, the root element has already passed in the event bubbling so it will trigger the event. You might have to handle it programmatically to achieve this. Try this

```
$("#content").on("hover", "a.animation", function(e) {
    if($("body:not(.zoomed)").length > 1){
       //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: funny thing is, if i put the length of body:not(.zoomed) into the console, i just get nothing. never ever.